# How to make partial_counter work with pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination

I have a blogging application in which User has_many posts. I am using pagination with Booststrap. How can I make the partial_count method work with pagination? Currently, the count resets on every page instead of carrying over across pages.

**posts_controller.rb**

```
def index
  @posts = Post.order("created_at desc").paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 12)
end
```

**views/posts/index.html.erb**

```
<%= render @posts %>
<%= will_paginate %>
```

**views/posts/_post.html.erb**

```
<%= post_counter +1%>
<%= post.name %>
```

The counter works fine on the first page. However, all subsequent pages also start with "1". How can I make subsequent pages start with (number of pages * 12 + 1) instead?

Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Try to initialize your counter with `@posts.offset`

Comment: Thanks @apneadiving. Do you mean something like `@posts.offset((current_page - 1) *12 +1)`? If so, do you know of a way to get `current_page`?

Comment: OK. using `<%= render @posts.offset %>` gives me an ArgumentError of `'12' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object that returns a valid partial path.` Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: don't render it, display it as you did with your counter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@posts.offset` to get the proper counter initialisation.